# SelectKBest Error: ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 0.55, 0.84, 0.72, 0.54, 0.59, 0.77, 0.85, 1.03, 1.62, 3.04, 3.6 ]),)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest ,chi2 

label_ds=pd.read_csv("D:/intern/bll_beijing.csv")  
array = label_ds.values

label_X  = array[:,1:]
label_y = array[:,0]

test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
fit = test.fit(label_X, label_y)
```

I received this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    fit = test.fit(label_X, label_y)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 349, in fit
    score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 217, in chi2
    Y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 307, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(y).transform(y)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 284, in fit
    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 97, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([0.55, 0.84, 0.72, 0.54, 0.59, 0.77, 0.85, 1.03, 1.62, 3.04, 3.6 ]),)

[Finished in 3.4s]
```

`[ 0.55, 0.84, 0.72, 0.54, 0.59, 0.77, 0.85, 1.03, 1.62, 3.04, 3.6 ]` is the first column of the csv document.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is there a question here? I just see a code dump and error message.

Comment: The answer is in the error message: "Unknown label type". A tuple of a (single) numpy array is not acceptable as a label.

Answer (score 3):

This `label_y` has continuous values.

But you have specified the scoring function as `chi2`. And according to the [documentation of chi2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2), this is only valid for classification tasks.

> Compute chi-squared stats between each non-negative feature and class.

For regression tasks, you can use the following:

- [f_regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression)
- [mutual_info_regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression)